# Linked List Operations in C Read Proof

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to write up all the linked list basic operations (push, pop, add_at_end, pop_from_end, add_at_index, pop_from_index). This is not a school assignment, even though it may look like one. I have written the code. I have tested it myself quite a bit, although I am no C guru. I would like it if you could tell me if there are any suggestions / corrections you have for the code in terms of efficiency, memory handling, readability, clarity etc.

The resulting code has been added here: http://vladotrocol.ro/wiki/linked-lists

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Node structure
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t *head); //print the list data iteratively
int push(node_t **head, int data); //add a node at the head of the list
int pop(node_t **head); //remove the node from the head of the list
int add_at_end(node_t **head, int data); //add a node at the end of the list
int remove_last(node_t **head); //remove the node from the end of the list
int add_at_index(node_t **head, int n, int data); //add a node at the nth position
int remove_by_index(node_t **head, int n); //remove the node at the nth position

int main()
{
    node_t *head = NULL; //create a new list

    //initialise the list with one element
    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    //check if memory allocation was possible
    if (head == NULL) { 
      return -1;
    }
    head->data = 1;
    head->next = NULL;

    //print the list
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
//print the list data iteratively
void print_list(node_t *head) {
    node_t *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
//add a node at the head of the list
int push(node_t **head, int data) {
    //create a new node with the diven data
    node_t *new_node = NULL;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    //check if memory allocation was possible
    if (new_node == NULL) { 
      return -1;
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head; //the new node link points to the old head of list
    *head = new_node; //the new node becomes the new head of list
    return 1;
}
//remove the node from the head of the list
int pop(node_t **head) {
    int retval = -1;
    //if the list is empty do nothing
    if (*head == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    //if there is only one node in the list make the list empty
    if ((*head)->next == NULL) {
        printf("here");
        retval = (*head)->data;
        free(*head);
        *head = NULL;
        return retval;
    }
    //if the list has multiple nodes
    node_t *next_node = NULL;
    next_node = (*head)->next; //get the second node
    retval = (*head)->data;
    free(*head);
    *head = next_node; //the second node becomes the head of the list
    return retval;
}
//add a node at the end of the list
int add_at_end(node_t ** head, int data) {
    node_t *new_node = NULL;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    //check if memory allocation was possible
    if (new_node == NULL) { 
      return -1;
    }
    //create the new node
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next=NULL;
    //if the list is empty the new node becomes the head of the list
    if(*head==NULL){
        *head = new_node;
        return 1;
    }
    //otherwise iterate to the end of the list
    node_t *current = *head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    //the last node instead of pointing to NULL points to the new node
    current->next = new_node;
    return 1;
}
//remove the node from the end of the list
int remove_last(node_t **head) {
    int retval = -1;
    //if the list is empty do nothing
    if (*head == NULL) { 
      return -1;
    }
    //if the list has one node only list beomes empty
    if ((*head)->next == NULL) {
        (*head)->data;
        free(*head);
        *head = NULL;
        return retval;
    }
    //if the list has multiple nodes go to second last one
    node_t *current = *head;
    while (current->next->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    retval = current->next->data;
    //remove the last node
    free(current->next);
    current->next = NULL;
    return retval;
}
//add a node at the nth position
int add_at_index(node_t **head, int n, int data) {
    /*if the list is empty or the position to be inserted at 
    is the first one add the new node at the head of the list*/ 
    if(n == 0 || *head==NULL){
        push(head, data);
        return 1;
    }
    //if the list is not empty we iterate n-2 times to reach the (n-1)th node
    node_t *current = *head;
    while(n>1 && current->next!=NULL){
        current = current->next;
        n--;
    }
    /*if we didn't perform all iterations it means the required 
    position is bigger than the length of the list*/
    if(n>1){
        return -1;
    }
    //if we reached the desired node we create a new one
    node_t *new_node = NULL;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    //check if memory allocation was possible
    if (new_node == NULL) { 
      return -1;
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    //the new node points to the node the current node was previously pointing to
    new_node->next = current->next;
    //the current node now points to our newly create node
    current->next = new_node; 
    return 1;
}
//remove the node at the nth position
int remove_by_index(node_t **head, int n) {
    /*if the list is empty or the required position is the first one use the pop
     function which removes the head node or does nothing if the list is emty*/
    if(n == 0||*head==NULL){
        pop(head);
        return 1;
    }

    //if the list has multiple elements got to the nth node
    node_t *current = *head;
    node_t *curr_head = NULL;
    while(n>0 && current->next!=NULL){
        curr_head = current; //this time we need to remember the previous node
        current = current->next;
        n--;
    }
    /*if the iterations have not completed it means 
    the list is emty and there is nothing to do*/
    if(n>0){
        return -1;
    }
    /*instead of pointing to the current node, 
    the previous node is now pointing to the next node*/
    curr_head->next = current->next;
    free(current); //delete the current node
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I feel like this question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: thank you for the suggestions I will move it asap

Comment: Also you could add some comments :)

Comment: adding them right now

Comment: `int remove_last(node_t * head) {` is wrong. Needs a pointer to pointer, too.

Comment: linked lists become way simpler to write if you use a sentry node (sentinel) see for example http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't thoroughly review all of the code, but I had a superficial look and I think there are a couple of points worth mentioning. Note that this may be subjective sometimes, not everyone agrees on using the same conventions. But here's a small list of what I think could be improved:

1.

In pointer declarations, you seem to follow the convention of placing a space between the star(s) and the identifier. I wouldn't recommend this. Why? Because the pointer declarator is not part of the primitive type (it's a declarator). If you put a space between the star and the identifier, you *will* write code like this someday:

```
int * x, y;
```

And mistakenly assume that `x` and `y` are pointers to `int`, whereas the reality is that `x` is a pointer, but `y` is an `int`. Do yourself a favor and write it like this instead:

```
int *x, y;
```

(Either way, this is not as bad as people who write `int* x,y` - that is really asking for trouble).

2.

Do not hardcode the type name when you are determining the amount of memory to allocate. Instead of this:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Use the more flexible form:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

`sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand, so it is always safe to do this. If you always do this, you're safe because you always allocate the correct amount of memory. Furthermore, it makes the code easier to maintain, because if the type of `head` changes, the code will still work and will still allocate the right amount of memory.

3.

`add_at_end()` and other functions that allocate memory are not checking whether `malloc()` was successful.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I will make the changes except for point 2. I believe, although it may be more flexible for more complex code, in this case using sizeof(node_t) keeps it clear and simple. I am making changes 1. and 3. though. Thank you.

Comment: @VladOtrocol You're welcome! Like I said, not everyone always agrees on what is better :)